# If B require A, then we said A ??? B?

Tags: verbs

In a situation of learning steps that need pre-skills in order to learn following skills, for instance, I must learn A first then I can learn B.

From above situation, I could say,

> B require A.

I know this would be fairy easy to use passive voice (A required by B), but I still wonder is there any verb to describe the above situation,

> A ???? B.

Comment: *B requires A*, with *-s*, and *A **is** required by B*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, it is better to say ***Learning B requires learning A*** or ***A is a prerequisite for learning B***.

However, it's understandable why you'd want to say *"A something<sup>?</sup> B"*. If you're looking for something short and easy to remember, perhaps simple words like *before* and *then* could work, e.g.

> *(You need to learn) **A before B***.

If a single word is not a must, and rephrasing is allowed, *prepare* or *ready* could work too, e.g.

> *(Learning) **A prepares you for** (learning) **B***.

<sub>As a side note, there are a few verbs which might work, but they all sound very awkward to me: *forerun*, *forebode*, *designate*. For example, *"A foreruns B"* might work, but rather awkwardly.</sub>

Comment: Don't you mean *"learning B requires learning A"*?

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, it should be as you commented indeed. I wonder why I couldn't catch the mistake even after I've read my own answer several times. Thank you!